# Change the name or the style of Microsofts Web Chat embedded on website

Tags: javascript, iframe, chat, bots, botframework

A bot created over Microsofts https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new to embed it e.g. using an iframe on a published website:

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/botName?s=SECRET_KEY'></iframe>
```

My question is: How to change elements of the web chat and how to change the style of the. E.g. change name of chat which is named "Chat" to "MyWebsite Chat". Using JS with getElementByID("idName") or $("#idName") does not work directly on loaded iframe.

Comment: You have no access at all to iframed content that comes from a different domain. If anything, this needs to happen in the configuration/settings of your bot. You’d have to check, what customization options they provide.

Comment: The customizations can be made on serverside for the requests and responses (e.g. you can configure default responses if no matches of the request exist). Where changes of the web chat look can be done I do not know. Therefore the question. You can select running programs like Skype and Web Chat but after clicking "Edit" e.g. for editing the web chat you can only add further URLs with two SECRET KEYS to use with an iframe and more not. On this way you can not change the style of the web chat or change any content like the web chat header.