# how to change the name of the bot header

Tags: botframework, bots

[image]

I need to change the name of [chat] header bot to Askme.
may i know how to change it in Microsoft bot.
Image is attched

Comment: What have you tried so far? How should we know which product you use?

Comment: How are you achieving the web chat console? If you don't provide information we can't help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186164/how-to-style-chat-window-using-css-when-using-microsoft-bot-framework

Comment: And possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430092/change-the-name-or-the-style-of-microsofts-web-chat-embedded-on-website?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Css of the QnA Bot embedded as webchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510099/change-the-css-of-the-qna-bot-embedded-as-webchat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023585/is-there-a-way-to-re-design-webchat-interface-of-microsoft-bot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style chat window using CSS when using Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186164/how-to-style-chat-window-using-css-when-using-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit Microsoft ChatBot UI design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620604/edit-microsoft-chatbot-ui-design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the iframe'd webchat, you can just modify the header's .innerHTML like this:

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header");
header[0].innerHTML = "<span>Askme</span>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you want to set it at the time of initialization and are using the `Botchat.App()` setup rather than the iframed version of webchat, you can set this in the parameter object sent to webchat:

```
BotChat.App({
botConnection:  botConnection,
user: { id: '1234', name: 'user'},
bot: { id: 'bot' },
chatTitle: "I'm a custom chat title"
}, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

The key parameter in this case being `chatTitle`; other options that can be sent to webchat can be found in the source code [right here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Chat.tsx#L17).

Comment: you are amazing mark, I just want to remove chat title so set it null